# HighMaps select map from list - Highcharts.geojson and Highcharts.mapDataIndex issues

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I want create a map where i can provide a drop list of all available mapDatas like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/all-maps

I have all the maps on my local system in @highcharts/map-collection (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection) and i want to use them instead of downloading from https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata at runtime.

In my typescript file I use the following imports

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highmaps";
import * as HC_DATA from "highcharts/modules/data";
HC_DATA(Highcharts);
```

In series I provide mapData as:

```
series: [{
            mapData: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']),
            name: 'My series',
            data: data,
        }]
```

I get the following exception at runtime:

*ng:///CreationModule/DashboardComponent.ngfactory.js:564 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined
    at Object.a.geojson*

Second issue: I want to get list of all available maps, I try to access Highcharts.mapDataIndex as it's explained in [demo/all-maps](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/all-maps), 
I get the error that mapDataIndex is undefined.

Please guide me how can i solve the above issues, i think im not using the required imports correctly, please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is related to the wrong import of map data. Simply `Highcharts.maps['custom/world']` is undefined. You can import map data as json and pass it to `chart.map` property like that:

```
const worldMap = require('@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json');

chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      map: worldMap
    },
    ...
}
```

---

> Second issue: I want to get list of all available maps, I try to
>   access Highcharts.mapDataIndex as it's explained in demo/all-maps, I
>   get the error that mapDataIndex is undefined.

mapDataIndex is not defined because it is not Highcharts default property and you have to load it (in the example is loaded from here: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/index.js?1). Check this description from `highcharts-angular` official wrapper documentation of how to load it: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper

**mapdata.js:**

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    factory(Highcharts);
  }
}(function (Highcharts) {

...
/* map data content here */
...

}));
```

In a chart component:

```
require('./mapdata')(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dm7xfb

**EDIT**

Map data can be also loaded using `import`:

```
import mapdata from "./mapdata";
import * as worldMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';

mapdata(Highcharts);
```

**mapdata.js:**

```
export default function (Highcharts) {
   Highcharts.mapDataIndex = {...}
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myhyjs

Comment: Is there any way we could achieve this without using require? require works when it is done at the outside the JS class but I am implementing drill-down map and while fetching the maps of the states using require, the build process fails. Interesting to note the app works fine on the local machine using ng serve.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check how to load files using `import`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add  a new config tag in tsconfig.json and keep the import like bellow

```
import mapdata from "./mapdata";
import worldMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';



chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    map: worldMap
  },
  ...
}

// in tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    ...
}
```

then you need to **restart ts server**
press ctrl+shift+p  and type Restart TS server